# LASSO with L1 loss function

Tags: lasso, loss-functions

I've been trying to figure out a way to perform LASSO with L1 loss function (instead of the L2 loss) but have been completely dumfounded as to how.

I've attempted to use the flare package's flare.slim() function but receive the error

```
Sparse Linear Regression with L1 Regularization.
Error in cor(xx, yy) : unused argument (yy)
```

Is there anyway to use glmnet or lars to accomplish this?  I'm referring to these as they seem to be the more normally used lasso packages.  I would also like to compare the outgoing results to lasso using the L2 loss function.

Thank you for your time.

I'm actually referring to lasso of the form

$$||y -Ax|| + \lambda ||w||$$

Instead of
$$(y-Ax)^2 + \lambda ||w||$$

So L1 loss and L1 penalty, instead of L2 loss and L1 penalty.    I know how to change the penalty but not the loss function.

Comment: The LASSO is *defined* as using L1 loss. This even shows up in the `[lasso]` tag's wiki excerpt (hold your mouse pointer over the tag & you'll see it.

Comment: glmnet has an alpha parameter that can be set to alpha=1 is L1, alpha=0 is L2.
alpha=1 is the lasso penalty, and alpha=0 the ridge penalty.

Comment: @gung I read the question so that the L1 loss does not refer to the coefficients (which are penalized by L1 in LASSO as you) but to the residuals, so that we basically try to minimize the (weighed) sum of the absolute values of the residuals and the absolute values of the coefficients. But the question seems to be ambigious.

Comment: Exactly.   I'm referring to calculating of coefficients not the penalty,  as that's well described in the package details.   I have edited the question to better represent that.  Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @user35650. I apologize for my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to have a look at the 'quantreg' package of R. Koenker et al. Using an L1 objective function for the model part is similar to median regression, a special case of quantile regression.

The package contains a function 'rq.fit.lasso' for the L1-penalized version of standard quantile regression.

Comment: The loss function of quantile regression is not the same though as L1...

Answer (score 0):

Using the `flare` package, this worked for me

```
fit = slim(X, y, method="lq", q=1)
```

to obtain L1 loss (`q=2` gives L2 loss). Unfortunately it's extremely slow though...

You might also like to take a look at [this](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi7wdnYjKDYAhVMaVAKHTG_C-IQFgg5MAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmath.mit.edu%2F~liewang%2FL1PLAD_Wang.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0SC1u8IECznT-I9A4br8c4) paper, he uses `lars` and `quantreg` to do LASSO penalized LAD/L1 regression... The `hqreg` and `pense` packages lso offer various penalized robust regresssion models...